# How do I know if an xml is being loaded by spring?

Tags: xml, spring

I have an application that is composed of several projects.

Each project has it's own set of spring xml configuration files (where you define beans).

I'm getting an exception saying spring wasn't able to autowire a field:
"no qualifying bean of type aaa.example found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency."

The fact is that inside this project I have an xml, and this xml is defining the bean that was mentioned by the error above. The xml is inside the project. The xml has the bean definition that matches what is set in the @autowired annotation inside the class. But still, spring is not able to do the wire.

I think that maybe spring is not loading that xml inside the project. But I don't know how to check what are the XMLs that Spring is loading to use as context (to load the beans).

As I mentioned, this application is composed of several projects. Each one has one or more XML files containing bean definitions. How can I know which one of those xml files are being used by spring?

Comment: do your application is a web app or a standalone ?

Comment: That error is saying that spring failed to do the beans injection as you defined it in your configuration. with that being said, you obviously need to modify the configuration file related to the discussed bean within the error message.